# URL content is not accessible from HTTP client other than web browser

Tags: ajax, client-server, http-status-code-404

I am trying to fetch each video segment of the `m3u8` playlist (containing 1300+ segments) from [this link](https://s94.upstream.to/hls/o2up3xy5qaysmvk4xqksumnblvwxrpgsfhdq6igsowufgoojz5q7clj6gs4a/index-v1-a1.m3u8). One's example URL is: `https://s94.upstream.to/hls/o2up3xy5qaysmvk4xqksumnblvwxrpgsfhdq6igsowufgoojz5q7clj6gs4a/seg-1-v1-a1.ts`. I can send successful Ajax (that returns proper content) from web browser (tested on Chrome 87 and old IE 11) - with both `XHR` and `fetch` APIs - while being on the page, from which the `m3u8` playlist is originally downloaded and from the target (video segment) page, because of CORS.

However, when i try to fetch it via Node.js or Postman i receive `404` error. I set `Referer`, `Host` and `Origin` headers based on those in the original request i sent from browser and even set `User-Agent` to the Chrome's one - but i still get `404`. I am aware that server can somehow check if request was sent by certain HTTP client, like web browser or Node or Postman etc. and therefore forbid/refuse to respond with a proper content. However, if i have prepared request, which is (as i consider) identical to one that i can successfully fetch data from browser, then how to check what differences i might missed that make the server refuse access to the target content on mentioned HTTP clients? How to ensure that one request is sent in identical shape on those clients?

I sometimes also get `404` when i try to reach the mentioned segment URL by copy-pasting it in the browser's address bar. Although accessing the content by clicking the request with right mouse button in *Devtools Network* panel always makes content to be downloaded. Why is this behavior inconsistent?

What i noticed during debugging is, when fetching is successful, then i receive `Content-Type: video/MP2T` header along with a CORS header, which is not the case for fetching via Node or Postman - then i receive `Content-Type: text/html` header (which probably indicates `404` page returned).

Comment: Can you provide your ajax request which is successfully receiving content

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fetch the proper content from mentioned URL by using [Copy as fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/devtools#fetch) option in Devtools Network panel. Apparently, some additional HTTP headers like ones prefixed with [`sec-fetch-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#fetch_metadata_request_headers) were needed for server to return valid response. It worked in both Node.js and Postman.